# a way to integrate $ \int \frac {\sin^2t}{\cos^3t} dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

is there a way to integrate $$ \int \frac {\sin^2t}{\cos^3t} dt$$ that would not be too difficult or complex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos t$ and let $u=\sin t$. You obtain
$$
\int\frac{\sin^2t}{(1-\sin^2t)^2}\cos t\,dt
$$

Comment: how do you replace the cosine then?

Comment: @Bak1139 $\cos^2 t=1-\sin^2 t$

Comment: @Bak1139 See extended version of hint.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to integrate $\sec x$?
If so then 
$$
\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^3 x}dx = -\int \frac{\sin x}{3}\frac{d}{dx}\sec^2 x dx
$$ then use by parts.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand equals $\tan^2 \sec = (\sec^2 - 1) \sec =  \sec^3 - \sec$

Here you go:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m121/secx.pdf
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed